# MarkLogic federation and data hubs

Tags: marklogic, federation

How can I achieve the virtual DB and Data Hub concept in MarkLogic? any guidance or steps to configure it ? Not been able to find the steps or any solution

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are referring to by the "virtual DB," but as far as a Data Hub is concerned, a decent starting point might be to look into the Data Hub Framework:

https://github.com/marklogic-community/marklogic-data-hub